# Select * from table WHERE `column` = x if `column` != -1

Tags: mysql

I need to make a select like,

```
Select * from table WHERE column = x if column != -1
```

but i have no idea for now.

Anyone know or made in past something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE column = x and column != -1` perhaps.

Comment: `WHERE column = -1 OR (column = x AND column !=-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also write like this,

```
Select * from table 
WHERE 
1 = case when column != -1 then 
        case when column = x then 1 else 0 end
    else 1 end
```

You can utilize case when in where clause.
Similarly you can add more conditional criteria like,

```
Select * from table 
WHERE 
1 = case when column != -1 then 
        case when column = x then 1 else 0 end
    else 1 end
AND 
1 = case when column1 [conditional operator] value then
        case when column1 = xx then 1 else 0 end
    else 1 end
```

This is just an example how you can integrate more conditional criteria together, even though you can add more case when in else part even.

Comment: You can add more conditions as well in the where clause.